# Docker - jpeglib.h not found

Tags: php, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, gd

I'm trying to start a docker container with `docker-compose up -d`, but i get the error `configure: error: jpeglib.h not found`

This is what the dockerfile looks like:

```
FROM php:7.2.18-apache

[..]

RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y -qq \
        libicu-dev \
        libfreetype6-dev \
        libjpeg62-turbo-dev \
        libmcrypt-dev \
        libpng-dev \
        libcurl4-openssl-dev \
        libzip-dev \
        software-properties-common  \
        libcurl3 curl \
        git \
        zip \
        unzip \
        inotify-tools \
        build-essential \
        libxml2-dev libxslt1-dev zlib1g-dev \
        git \
        mysql-client \
        sshpass \
        gnupg \
        nano \
        sudo \
        vim \
        graphviz \
        netcat-openbsd \
        ant \

 [...]

RUN docker-php-ext-install iconv mbstring opcache
RUN docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-freestyle-dir=/usr/include/  --with-jpeg-dir=/usr/include/
RUN docker-php-ext-install gd
```

I already tried several things like using `--with-freestyle --with-jpeg` instead of `--with-freestyle-dir=/usr/include/  --with-jpeg-dir=/usr/include/` resulting in `configure: error: png.h not found`.
I also tried it with `docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc)` which didn't work either.

Does someone have an idea what could be done about it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest you to try to use swap the images

`Old: "FROM php:7.2.18-apache"`

`New: "FROM php:7.4-apache"`

If you still want to use mysql, you need to change the mysql part to
"default-mysql-client"
And delete the "libcurl3 curl" part, you can't use libcurl3 and libcurl4 simultaneously

Comment: That did it. Thanks.